# Gradle is unable to find latest google play services file

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm currently getting this error

> Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0.
>   Required by:
>     app:unspecified

I have updated the google play services sdk in Android Studios.
This is my gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
}
```

this is in my manifest application

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I have tried to clean and rebuild but I still get the error.

Comment: "I have updated the google play services sdk in Android Studios" -- you need to update the Google Repository.

Comment: Open up the SDK Manager

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have thought to do that.